# Jmeter - How to stop While Controller once getting the expected values from Data Base?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run the performance script which has API which takes the payload as file from S3 and submit to target system. After the request is completed I need to login to db and verify the status of the transaction. Here there is delay in getting inserted to db which is fast for payload with small file size. As I started submitting large files 1 GB to 15 GB, there will be delay in inserting a table.

So the JDBC request which has modified_date will be "null" and Status will be "null" for large payload when request is new. I have used constant timer but not sure how long it takes to insert in table. Is there any way I can make jdbc request to wait till i get result for modified_date will be "2021-02-10 18:17:44.538" and status will be "message deliver" for message table.
1)How to make loop keep on running till both the values inserting in the message table ?
2)How to stop while controller once I getting the expected values for modified_date and status ?

Answer (score 0):

1. While Controller is being executed until the condition is met
2. You can combine more than one condition if the function allows it, the most powerful is probably [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

Example condition:

```
${__groovy((vars.get('Status') != 'message deliver' || vars.get('modified_date') == 'null'),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

In the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class intance which provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in current context. See the JavaDoc for all available functions. You might also be interested in Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy article which provides more information on JMeter API shortcuts available to [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and __groovy() function